# syntax error near unexpected token `fi' for bash script that checks for file

Tags: bash, docker, kubernetes

I am trying to set up conditions in the bash script that will make sure if the file exists skip the entire code and go to the next part

'''

```
            echo "k8s: starting the init script"
              if [ ! -e /etc/sawtooth/keys/validator.priv ]; then
                echo $pbft0priv > /etc/sawtooth/keys/validator.priv
                echo $pbft0pub > /etc/sawtooth/keys/validator.pub
              fi &&
            echo "k8s: checking for keys"
              if [ ! -e /root/.sawtooth/keys/my_key.priv ]; then
                sawtooth keygen my_key
              fi &&
            echo "k8s: checking for config-genesis.batch"
              if [ ! -e /var/lib/sawtooth/genesis.batch.file ]; then
                if [ ! -e config-genesis.batch ]; then
                  sawset genesis -k /root/.sawtooth/keys/my_key.priv -o config-genesis.batch
                fi &&
            echo "k8s: sleeping for 30 sec"
                sleep 30 &&
            echo sawtooth.consensus.pbft.members=["\"$pbft0pub\",\"$pbft1pub\",\"$pbft2pub\",\"$pbft3pub\",\"$pbft4pub\""] &&
                if [ ! -e config.batch ]; then
                  sawset proposal create \
                    -k /root/.sawtooth/keys/my_key.priv \
                    sawtooth.consensus.algorithm.name=pbft \
                    sawtooth.consensus.algorithm.version=1.0\
                    sawtooth.consensus.pbft.members=["\"$pbft0pub\",\"$pbft1pub\",\"$pbft2pub\",\"$pbft3pub\",\"$pbft4pub\""] \
                    sawtooth.publisher.max_batches_per_block=1200 \
                    -o config.batch
                fi && \
                fi &&
              if [ ! -e /var/lib/sawtooth/genesis.batch ]; then
                  sawadm genesis config-genesis.batch config.batch
              fi &&
             
              sawtooth-validator -vv \
                --endpoint tcp://$SAWTOOTH_0_SERVICE_HOST:8800 \
                --bind component:tcp://eth0:4004 \
                --bind consensus:tcp://eth0:5050 \
                --bind network:tcp://eth0:8800 \
                --scheduler parallel \
                --peering static \
                --maximum-peer-connectivity 10000
```

'''

But I get error as
line 28: syntax error near unexpected token `fi' line 28:`                     fi &&'

This is line no. 28:

```
 26:  -o config.batch
 27:               fi && \
 28:               fi &&
```

Comment: `&&` has to be followed by a command name; `fi` is not a valid command name. It looks like you simply duplicated that line, as there doesn't appear to be a corresponding `if` that it closes.

Comment: Thanks for reverting,  I am trying to put a condition for the line,

                  if [ ! -e /var/lib/sawtooth/genesis.batch.file ]; then

Comment: BTW, in general, http://shellcheck.net/ is your friend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is in line 27:

```
fi && \
```

That `&& \` doesn't belong there. It's the last `if` in the block, so you shouldn't put `&&` there since there are no commands afterwards.

```bash
if true; then
    if true; then
        echo one
    fi &&
    if true; then
        echo two
    fi
fi &&
echo three
```